# EINTR on 'wait' syscall

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, posix

From `man -e 2 wait`:

> The call wait(&status) is equivalent to:
>              waitpid(-1, &status, 0);

errno values:

> EINTR  WNOHANG was not set and an unblocked signal or a SIGCHLD was
>   caught; see signal(7).

So I from my understanding of above, if we are blocked in 'wait' and receiving a signal (SIGCHLD), the call should return with -1 and errno set to EINTR.
Though running the following snippet will prove that wait is actually restarted (linux 4.15.0-43, glibc 2.23):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static void sigchld_handler(int signo)
{
    const char *const msg = "\nSIGCHLD";

    (void)signo;
    write(STDERR_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t wait_ret = 0, pid = 0;
    int status = 0, ret = -1;

    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &(struct sigaction){
       .sa_handler = sigchld_handler,
    }, NULL);

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
       perror("\nfork: ");
       goto Exit;
    }

    if (!pid)
    {
       sleep(3);
       return 0;
    }

    if ((wait_ret = wait(&status)) < 0)
    {
       perror("\nwait: ");
       goto Exit;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "\nwait done, pid %d", wait_ret);
    ret = 0;

Exit:
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    return ret;
}
```

SA_RESTART is not set - so why does 'wait' restart.?
Actual output:

> ```
> SIGCHLD
> wait done, pid 15242
> ```

Expected by me output:

> ```
> SIGCHLD
> wait: Interrupted system call
> ```

Note `kill -CHLD <waiting process>` manually from shell will give the expected result.

Also note that running the code on FreeBSD 11.2 will give the expected result as well - wait is interrupted with error on child exit.

Comment: I think that EINTR is triggered only when SIGCHLD is caught and `waitpid` would not otherwise return (i.e. some child other than the one waited for exited).

Comment: you mean that errno == EINTR applies only to waitpid - then the question where is it stated in specs. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html says that EINTR does apply to both.

Comment: wait() is probably just a wrapper for waitpid().

Comment: The call wait(&status) is equivalent to: waitpid(-1, &status, 0); as qouted in question.

Comment: Yes, and waitpid(-1, &status, 0) also never returns EINTR. Also note, that system call is not restarted, it just returns. If you try to wait() for the same child in signal handler you see, it is already handled.

Comment: Already tried SIGUSR1 and SIGCHLD (mentioned in question) - the expected result is shown.

Comment: I think that @ErkiA hit the nail on the head... Since the child process have exited normally the `wait` function returns normally, even though you catched the `SIGCHLD` signal. And you have to remember that `SIGCHLD` is also sent for *other* events, like the child process being stopped.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

There is a subtlety of interpretation here.  You have to start with:

> on success, [`wait`] returns the process ID of the terminated child; on error, -1 is returned.

([Linux wait(2) manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid))

The docs about `errno` values need to be interpreted in that light: ***in the event that `wait()` returns -1***, thus indicating an error, and `errno` is set to `EINTR`, the interpretation is that a `SIGCHLD` or unblocked (other) signal interrupted the wait.  But that does not imply that receipt of a `SIGCHLD` must cause `wait()` to fail.  In particular, `wait()` will complete normally instead of raising an error when the `SIGCHLD` arises from termination of one of the process's children.

Before being too critical of the docs here, do consider that

- a `SIGCHLD` may be delivered for reasons other than that a child has terminated
- the error descriptions apply to all the functions in that group, and some of them can wait for specific children only.  These could be interrupted by a `SIGCHLD` from some child that they are not waiting for.

The wording of the docs also seems to suggest that a `SIGCHLD` might cause one or more of these functions to fail with `EINTR` *even if that signal is blocked*.  I would find such behavior surprising, but remember where I started: that that result is among the possible interpretations of an `EINTR` error does not necessarily imply that it can actually happen.

Comment: FreeBSD also interrupts wait on SIGCHLD on child exit (the output is expected one).

Comment: And, that, too, is consistent with the docs, @GreenTree.  They allow but do not require a `SIGCHLD` to interrupt the `wait`.  What they do require is that ***if*** the `wait` is interrupted for such a reason ***then*** `wait()` shall set `errno` to `EINTR` and return -1.  As this answer already describes.

Comment: If a blocked call to one of the following interfaces is interrupted
       by a signal handler, then the call is automatically restarted after
       the signal handler returns if the SA_RESTART flag was used; otherwise
       the call fails with the error EINTR:
...
* wait(2), wait3(2), wait4(2), waitid(2), and waitpid(2)
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/siginterrupt.3.html 

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/siginterrupt.3.html

Comment: the quote above explicitly states that wait should fail with EINTR when interrupted by a signal handler. it is interrupted by signal handler in the example, so I suppose that is the case described. though maybe it's also the subtlety of interpretation.

Comment: Sure, @GreenTree, but that does not define whether an incoming `SIGCHLD` should be interpreted to *interrupt* `wait()`.  That's what typical implementations wait *for*.

Comment: I do understand what you say -
OK, even if neither posix nor linux defines this behaviour (which I doubt), we have fact of interruption under linux implementation - if you run gdb you would see that 'wait()' is interrupted by SIGCHLD - interrupted in terms of 2.4.4 Signal Effects on Other Functions from https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04

Comment: @GreenTree, some signals are special, either in general or under specific circumstances.  You will have read about `SIGCONT`, for example, there and elsewhere in chapter 2.4 of POSIX.

Comment: Sticking with one standard domain, POSIX has this to say about [`wait()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html): "The wait() function shall cause the calling thread to become blocked until status information generated by child process termination is made available to the thread, or until delivery of a signal whose action is either to execute a signal-catching function or to terminate the process, or an error occurs."

Comment: Status information generated by the child process becomes available to `wait()` no later than when the process receives a `SIGCHLD`, thus the thread blocked in `wait()` could be unblocked for either of two reasons, and the requirements on its subsequent behavior differ based on which you choose.

Comment: But if you are unsatisfied with my answer, @GreenTree, then you are welcome to write your own.  Clearly you have been studying the documentation.  Researching and writing out a convincing argument for a position on the question would be a useful exercise.